# Is there a way to use react multiple select with this

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-select

I formerly have a checkbox like this

```
renderCategoriesMD() {
  const { classes, categoriesArray } = this.props;
  const { checkedCategories, reset } = this.state;
  if (categoriesArray && categoriesArray.length > 0) {
    return categoriesArray.map((cat, index) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControlLabel
            key={index}
            control={
              <Checkbox
                tabIndex={-1}
                onClick={() => this.handleToggleCats(index)}
                checked={checkedCategories.indexOf(index) !== -1}
                checkedIcon={<Check className={classes.checkedIcon} />}
                icon={<Check className={classes.uncheckedIcon} />}
                classes={{
                  checked: classes.checked,
                  root: classes.checkRoot,
                }}
              />
            }
            classes={{ label: classes.label }}
            label={
              <Typography style={{ fontSize: 13 }}>
                {cat.name || ""}
              </Typography>
            }
          />
          {!reset && (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>
              {this.renderUnderSubCategoriesMD(cat)}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  return null;
}
```

What this does is populate options of checkboxes like the image below.

[image: screenshot result]

what i want to achieve now is to have react-select of multiple options so instead of checkboxes i can select the options from react select.

```
<Select
  value={this.state.value}
  name="filter__statistics"
  options={options}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  multi={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the npm packages, it is very easy to use and implement. [npm react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select)

There is an example

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        selectedOption: null,
    };
    handleChange = selectedOption => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    };
    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (
            <Select
                value={selectedOption}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i get the options to show the previous options i have in the question